# import js file in js file for webdev

Tags: javascript, file, web, import

I have a js file called project specific js.js and in that file I want to import another js file for general js called logic.js in the js folder

```
import 'js/logic.js';
```

in devtools when I run the html that imports project specific js i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed it turns out because I wasn't running a localhost for some reason you cant import other js files except modules like react. now I am running localhost and in the script tag importing projectSpecificJs.js i have type set to module so :`<script type="module" src="projectSpeceficJs.js></script>"`

Answer (score 0):

Just for further information:

```js
import 'file.js'
```

Is only for nodejs / module html attribute

Also here's some quick info related to the topic:

The whole concept behind using the “import” statement instead of “require” in Node.js is to shift from the CommonJS module system to the ECMAScript Module System. [Reference](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-the-import-statement-in-node-js-d43ce83e5b44)